# Ignoring tabs and spaces in a python string

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, whitespace

I need to compare two string in python, first string is read from .xlsx file and second is an output from stdout.readlines().

Below code is to get command output.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(testCommand)
op = stdout.readlines()
print("op =\n"+str(op))
str1 = "".join(op)
```

Since some commands output begin with \t or might have \t in between .

For Eg : Below command output begin with \t and after LEN there is \t.

```
#   PASS_MIN_LEN    Minimum acceptable password length.
PASS_MIN_LEN    5
```

And xlsx file is having

```
# PASS_MIN_LEN Minimum acceptable password length.
PASS_MIN_LEN 5
```

As .xlsx comparison string doesn't have \t, how can i ignore \t while comparing two string.

```
if cmdOutput== xlsxOutput:
```

is not working.

I tried to trim the cmdOutput with \t, it didn't worked. 
Any approach can i follow?

Comment: Is `op` a list?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm 99.999999999% sure it is. `stdout` looks like a file, and `file.readlines()` returns a list. Not to mention the OP's use of `str.join`.

Comment: @ChristianDean Mhm... thought so... I suppose OP tried something like `str(op).strip()`.

Comment: Its is a list.                                                     
[u'#\tPASS_MIN_LEN\tMinimum acceptable password length.\n', u'PASS_MIN_LEN\t5\n'
]

Comment: @Sameer So you want to replace all tabs with one space?

Comment: Perhaps `map(lambda s: s.replace('\t', ' '), op)`, @Sameer? You can't use any variation of `str.strip` here since it only strips whitespace from the front and back of a string.

Comment: @COLDSPEED while comparing two string, it should treat \t and a space (one or multiple).

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to replace tabs with a space, perhaps `str.replace` is simple enough. But that doesn't leave the trailing newlines. You might consider the replacement followed by `str.strip`. For example:

```
op = [x.replace('\t', ' ').strip() for x in op]
print(op)

['# PASS_MIN_LEN Minimum acceptable password length.', 'PASS_MIN_LEN 5']
```

If you have other kinds of characters, or multiple characters (missing data, or the like), a more aggressive approach with `re`gex may be considered:

```
import re
op = [x for x in map(lambda x: re.sub('\s+', ' ', x).strip(), op)]
print(op) 

['# PASS_MIN_LEN Minimum acceptable password length.', 'PASS_MIN_LEN 5']
```

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much works. I have a \n   in between. And my xlsx file has a new line entry.                                                                         '#\tPASS_MIN_LEN\tMinimum acceptable password length.\n', u'PASS_MIN_LEN\t5\n'

Comment: @COLDSPEED second regex is not handling \n. trying to get it fixed. its already 2AM.

Comment: @Sameer Are you sure it's a new line and not a literal backslash followed by n? Because that regex would handle the new line if it was actually one.

Comment: @COLDSPEED its not a literal backslash, stdout.readlines() is giving me        [u'#\tPASS_MIN_LEN\tMinimum acceptable password length.\n', u'PASS_MIN_LEN\t5\n'
]                                                                                                                           And doing a  "".join() on it, \n is treated as new line.

Comment: @Sameer add a `flags=re.MULTILINE` to the regex. `[x for x in map(lambda x: re.sub('\s+', ' ', x, flags=re.M).strip(), op)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the tab in the command output string with a space.

For example:

```
cmdOutput.replace('\t', ' ') == xlsxOutput
```

Comment: Rather than having to repeatedly do `str.replace(...)` on each element, why not just do it once on the entire list of strings?

Comment: Yes, calling replace on the whole list would make the most sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Read the description for [strip() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) in official python documentation.

"Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed."

So, the characters within the string remain unchanged. Using replace() method is the best solution for your problem.

```
>>> str1 = "PASS_MIN_LEN\t5"
>>> str2 = "PASS_MIN_LEN 5"
>>> str1.replace('\t', ' ') == str2
True
```